Trying to fit model VAR
I am trying to find best fit for model but error:
LinAlgError: 7-th leading minor of the array is not positive definite keeps popping
I dont know what I am doing wrong beacuse all tutorials had similar steps to me.
**##checking Stationarity and duing data Stationary**

import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller

def adf_test(series, column_name):
    result = adfuller(series)
    print(f'ADF Test for {column_name}:')
    print(f'ADF Statistic: {result[0]}')
    print(f'p-value: {result[1]}')
    print(f'Critical Values:')
    for key, value in result[4].items():
        print(f'    {key}: {value}')
    if result[1] > 0.05:
        print(f"Conclusion: {column_name} is not stationary. Taking 2 differences...\n")
        series_diff = series.diff(2).dropna()
        result_diff = adfuller(series_diff)
        print(f'ADF Test for {column_name} (after 2 differences):')
        print(f'ADF Statistic: {result_diff[0]}')
        print(f'p-value: {result_diff[1]}')
        print(f'Critical Values:')
        for key, value in result_diff[4].items():
            print(f'    {key}: {value}')
        if result_diff[1] > 0.05:
            print(f"Warning: {column_name} is still not stationary after 2 differences. Consider alternative methods to make the series stationary.\n")
        else:
            print(f"Conclusion: {column_name} is stationary after 2 differences.\n")
    else:
        print(f"Conclusion: {column_name} is stationary.\n")

columns = ["Close","High","Volume","sma_8","sma_13","rsi_14","ema12"]
for col in columns:
    adf_test(train[col], col)

train.head()


TRAIN df
After that I am trying to find best fit for model:

model = VAR(train)
for i in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]:
    result = model.fit(i)
    print('Lag Order =', i)
    print('AIC : ', result.aic)
    print('BIC : ', result.bic)
    print('FPE : ', result.fpe)
    print('HQIC: ', result.hqic, '\n')

But error shows...
I tried to make somehow my my matrix positive definite (there are no Nans and blan spaces) but it doesnt work at all. I am folowing tutorial and guy had no problems with that.
